# Handlebars helper with ES6

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I want to write a block helper to check if a section should displayed for a certain role:

```
{{#allowApprover "EMP"}} 
<!-- content -->
{{/allowApprover}}
```

And the helper is defined like:

```
allowApprover: (currentRole, options) => {
     return permit(currentRole) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this)
}
```

the above code doesn't work, I guess it's because the `this` behaves differently in arrows, but I don't know how to make this work, and another question, what does `options.fn` do exactly?

Comment: Are you using babel?

Comment: @emd yeah, of course.

Comment: Just write a regular function instead of an arrow function.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, with this error message:

```
Cannot read property '_sections' of null
```

As @torazaburo commented, you should, in this case, write a regular function instead of an arrow function.

Here's why, by the words of a great article from Mozilla.

[ES6 in depth arrow functions](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-arrow-functions/)

> What’s this?
>
> There is one subtle difference in behavior between ordinary function
>   functions and arrow functions. Arrow functions do not have their own
>   this value. The value of this inside an arrow function is always
>   inherited from the enclosing scope.

Going forward, in the same article:

> Use non-arrow functions for methods that will be called using the
>   object.method() syntax. Those are the functions that will receive a
>   meaningful this value from their caller.

Answer (score 0):

Estevan is right. But I won't acccept it. My project requires modular functions to be easily testable. So I came up with a workaround. It requires wrapping the method and dropping the use of `this`. But it works.

Example:

```js
const helpers = {
  ifTruthy: (...args: any[]): HandlebarOptions => {
    const { fn, inverse } = args.pop();
    const values = args;
    const anyIsTruthy = values.some((element) => Boolean(element));
    return anyIsTruthy ? fn() : inverse();
  }
};

helpersKeys.forEach(key => {
  handlebarsInstance.registerHelper(key, function callback(...args) {
    const options = args.pop();
    const newOptions = { ...options };
    newOptions.fn = () => options.fn(this);
    newOptions.inverse = () => options.inverse(this);
    return helperMethods[key](...args, newOptions);
  });
});
```